# How do you create an extension to Chart.js?

Tags: chart.js

I have created a new chart type:

```
Chart.types.Line.extend({
    name: "LineWithRectangle",
    draw: function () {
        Chart.types.Line.prototype.draw.apply(this, arguments);

        var startPoint = this.datasets[0].points[this.options.startIndex]
        var endPoint = this.datasets[0].points[this.options.endIndex]
        var scale = this.scale

        this.chart.ctx.fillStyle = "#808080";
        ctx.globalAlpha = 0.2;

        this.chart.ctx.fillRect(startPoint.x,
                                scale.startPoint,
                                endPoint.x - startPoint.x,
                                scale.endPoint - scale.startPoint);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.globalAlpha = 1;


        this.chart.ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        this.chart.ctx.fillText("EVENT DAY",
                                startPoint.x + (endPoint.x - startPoint.x) / 2,
                                scale.startPoint + 20);
    }
});
```

I placed this code in another file and referenced in the page :

```
<script src="~/lib/charts-js/Chart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/lib/charts-js/ChartExtensions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But when I try to use it I'm not getting a chart object in the debugger:

```
new Chart(ctx.children[0].getContext("2d")).LineWithRectangle(data, { pointHitDetectionRadius: 0.05, animation: false, startIndex: start, endIndex: end })
```

Chrome is not reporting a ChartType object like it does for built in chart types but says "not available".

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code expects different values for `ctx` in the main code vs. your extension. In your main code it seems like a DOM node and in your extension you are using it as a context.

Just add

```
  var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
```

after `Chart.types.Line.prototype.draw.apply(this, arguments);` and it should work. If not, check if your main code variables are all defined with correct values (`start`, `end` and `ctx`)